FreeRtos : Only one task Running
A few days ago, I was running FreeRTOS smoothly without any issues, but when my STM32f4XX vgt6 microcontroller experienced a short circuit, I purchased a microcontroller with the same version, but my friend doesn't remember which online store he bought it from (I will include a photo of the old microcontroller and the link to purchase the new microcontroller). When I ran the old code, no tasks were executed. Then I created 2 tasks with different priorities and ran a simple code, but only the task with the highest priority was executed. I'm confused, is this a code configuration error, microcontroller damage, or what?
I ran it using the Arduino IDE, then converted it to a binary file and uploaded it using the ST-LINK utility.
#include <HardwareTimer.h>
#include <STM32FreeRTOS.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.setTx(PA9);
  Serial.setRx(PA10);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(5000);
   xTaskCreate(Sensor,
          "Sensor",
          1024,
          NULL,
          1,  //Priority Lebih Rendah
          NULL);
  xTaskCreate(Kaki,
          "Kaki",
          1024,  //awal 512
          NULL,
          2,  //Priority Lebih Tinggi
          NULL);
 vTaskStartScheduler();
}

void loop() {

}

Task 1
void Sensor(void *pvParameters) {
  while (1) {
   Serial.println("Sensor");
   vTaskDelay(10 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
 }
}

Task 2
void Kaki(void *pvParameters) {
  while (1) {
    Serial.println("Kaki");
    vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
  }
}

Photo of the old microcontroller
Back Board
Front Board
The purchase link for the new STM32f4.
Link Purchase

Do you have the same behavior if you: 1. invert the priorities, 2. change the task creation order ?

The original board seems to be this one : https://stm32-base.org/boards/STM32F407VGT6-STM32F4XX-M.html
Are you sure that the new board has the same chip (STM32F407VGT6) and not the one with less flash (STM32F407VET6)

@Mathieu Yes, I have reversed the priorities and task sequences, but still only tasks with the highest priority are executed.

@Mathieu Previously, I inherited two STM34F407 VGT and VET microcontrollers from my senior, which were purchased a long time ago. All of them function well, and both are from DevEBox

@Mathieu Do you know any information or places to buy STM32F407 VGT from DevEBox? I'm having trouble finding it in Indonesia.

You should check the return value from xTaskCreate(). Perhaps one of the tasks is not being created.

@pmacfarlane
Translation: "I have tried to check the returned values, and the program returned 'Task 1 created' and 'Task 2 created', so both tasks have been created."
Here are some codes that I consider important.
#include <STM32FreeRTOS.h>
BaseType_t xReturned1;
BaseType_t xReturned2;
xReturned1 = xTaskCreate(Sensor, "Sensor", 512, NULL, 1, NULL);
xReturned2 = xTaskCreate(Kaki, "Kaki", 512, NULL, 2,NULL);
if (xReturned1 == pdPASS) {
Serial.println("Task 1 created");
}
if (xReturned2 == pdPASS) {
Serial.println("Task 2 created");
}

Could it be something is wrong with the clock of the OS? Imagine OS starts, but its clock isn't configured, so it starts the higher priority task and never ticks and therefore never switches context?

@Ilya I'd figure vTaskDelay would've explicitly stopped the task and scheduled another (which would do the same at which point both tasks are stopped waiting for timeout to never come). Altough the description kinda suggests something wrong with peripherals (board bricked, bought another exact same board - same SN even!!? - and it doesn't work the same)

Thank you for all the answers that have been given, I have found the problem, 1. where FreeRtos only works on the old library, when I update the library, freeRtos doesn't work again.
2. When I bought the board I was looking for, FreeRtos could work with any version of the library.
